# Mobility scooter motor overvolting/cooling

Tags: motor, dc

I have a 8 1/2" motor originally running 24 V 90 A, but I've been running up to 82 V, 20 A with no problem. How high can I overvolt this? I'd like to have it as high as 110 V. The controller is no issue at this time.

Comment: If the drivers are current limited you may actually be undervolting it.

Comment: Until the rotor will dissect due to centrifugal forces, or the wire insulation break.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no way to determine the maximum operating voltage for successful operation. It is possible that the manufacturer started with a motor designed for 90 volts or higher and modified the motor slightly for 24 volt operation. You probably know that the speed is proportional to voltage and you are running the motor at about 3-1/2 times the 24 volt speed. If the rotor structure, bearings and dynamic balance are not suitable for the higher speed, it may not last very long. It is unlikely to overheat while running at less than the design current. The motor might experience excessive commutator sparking or flashover. The motor may have a self-cooling fan that will add more load as the speed increases.